# Embedding a live 2D heatmap on a Qt designer GUI using PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, heatmap, qt-designer

I am trying to embed a live 8x8 heatmap on a Qt designer based GUI. The heatmap is supposed to refresh at ~30Hz. I have created a widget on the GUI window and promoted it to a 'Heatmap' class that I created in a python file.

Based on the research I have done online, `pyqtgraph` seems like something I could use for this. I am trying to inherit the `Heatmap` class from the `pyqtgraph.ImageItem` class but getting an error when running the GUI. Here's how the Qt designer output file (created from the .ui file) is creating an instance of the `Heatmap` class:

```
self.heatmap = Heatmap(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
```

where `verticalLayoutWidget_2` is a vertical layout widget I created on the GUI window.

But it gives the following error:

> TypeError: addWidget(self, QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = 0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Heatmap'

I am not sure if the packages I am trying to use are the best or even the correct ones for creating the live heatmap.
I'd appreciate any help that would point me in the right direction. I am new to python based GUI development so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inheriting from ImageItem, your heatmap does not inherit from QWidget, which is the required input to addWidget. Try inheriting from ImageView, which inherits directly from QWidget.